# {"detail" : "Invalid Token"} error in oauth2

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I am just getting started with the rest api. I followed django-oauth2-provider for authenticating users.

So far I have a simple view that response some contents only if the `request.user` is authenticated.Heres how my view looks:

```
def get(self, request, format=None):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        person_value = PersonEducation.objects.all()
        serializer = PersonEducationSerializer(person_value, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response(json.dumps({'success':'False', 'message':'login required'}))
```

I have successfully created the client, request access token for each client and while trying to access the api with that access token i got, it keeps giving me the error `{"detail": "Invalid token"}` from authorization server.

I am requesting access token from this code snippet:

```
curl -X POST -d "client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=password&username=YOUR_USERNAME&password=YOUR_PASSWORD" http://localhost:8000/oauth2/access_token/
```

I am accessing the api from:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <your-access-token>" http://localhost:8000/api/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until i did the following for the post:

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer your-access-token" http://localhost:8000/api/

So , without less than, greater than simbols .

I hope this help